# Regex in R - returning only single integers (less than 10) from integer string (up to 100)

Tags: r, regex

I have a file with peoples ages, and want to subset age ranges (eg. under10, 35-44 etc).

Whilst age ranges of double digit numbers works fine using grep:

```
X_35_44 <- X[ grep("35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44", X$Age) , ]
```

When trying to subset for anything under 10 eg:

```
X_10under <- X[ grep("0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|", X$Age) , ]
```

I am returned any age with a 1 in it (eg. 31) or a 2 or a 3, rather than just those numbers under 10.

How do I ensure that this doesn't happen?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to convert `X$Age <- as.integer(X$Age)` and use `X_10under <- subset(X, Age <= 10)`?

Comment: [so you used regex to solve a problem and now you have another problem?](https://xkcd.com/1171/)

Comment: If you _really_ need to use regex, you need to specify that what comes before and after is not a digit: `paste0('\\D', 1:10, '\\D', collapse = '|')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the principle of not accepting failed code, but rather delivering a more effective coding solution, I'm going to disagree with the regex strategy and suggest you instead use `cut` or `findInterval`.

```
X <- data.frame(Ages = sample(1:85, 300, repl=TRUE))
X$age_cat <- cut(X$Age, c(0, 10, 45, 60, 75, Inf), labels=c("under10", 
    '10-44','45-59','60-74','75+'), right=FALSE, include.lowest=TRUE)
head(X)
#=========    
  Ages age_cat
1   65   60-74
2   34   10-44
3   19   10-44
4   79     75+
5    5 under10
6   51   45-59
```

Comment: That worked a treat thanks - hadn't used cut before and it simplifies the multiple lines of code covering each age group right down.

Answer (score 1):

A solution with

> ifelse()

```
 as.integer(df$age)
    df$age_cat <- ifelse(df$age < 10, "age_0-10", ifelse(10 < df$age < 20, "age_10-20", "age_20-"))
```

Choose your own range ...